# What that is the attr() CSS function?

Tags: css, mozilla

I am saw in  the documentation the mozilla y i wonder how workings the attribute:  **attr()**.

this is the docs that I seem : [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr)

OK I understand this code:

```css
p::before {
  content: attr(data-foo) " ";
}
```

```html
<p data-foo="hello">world</p>
```

but my question is where could use attr() in css and what is diffrent between attr() from css and attr from javascript.

Comment: see: https://www.quackit.com/css/functions/css_attr_function.cfm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`attr()` used to manipulate attribute values.

In your code

```
<p data-foo="hello">world</p>
```

`data-foo` is an attribute

so

`content: attr(data-foo) " ";`

here `attr(data-foo)` is the value ie hello
so the output is hello world

Comment: That I know , but you can give me a example to life true how developer for that its working ?

Comment: It is mostly used with javascript combination to select elements or have some metadata about the element example if your div represnts the user then you may have data-user-id  attribute to that div so onlcick of div you will get to know the user id etc

Comment: One use case for this function I know is outputting link URLs in print styles (like `@media print { a[href]::after { content: ' (' attr(href) ')'; } }` in the simplest form). Unfortunately, all browsers currently support it only as defined in CSS2.1 (string-only), so this is probably the only case where it's useful(

Comment: I have one example for responsive use: [see link](https://www.nickedeye.com/css-attribute-function-with-media-query-responsive-code-sample/) @DeepakKumarTP